# How to update json value with dropdown list

Tags: javascript

Can anyone teach me how can I update json value using the the dropdown list.
In JavaScript

HTML:

```html
<select id="currency" onchange="getSelectValue();">
    <option value="Singapore Dollar">Singapore Dollar</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="Malaysia Riggit">Malaysia Riggit</option>
</select>
```

JSON :

```js
{
"products": [
    {
       "name": "Apple",
        "price": "2.50",
        "code": "SGD"
    },
    {
       "name": "Orange",
        "price": "2.50",
        "code": "SGD"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: FYI it's [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), not _"Jason"_

Comment: Java or JavaScript ?

Comment: is javascript - Mister Jojo

Comment: and Thanks -Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can create a select in javascript like this, focus on the `<script />`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Javascript - Select</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
<script>
    const {products} = JSON.parse('{ "products": [ { "name": "Apple", "price": "2.50", "code": "SGD" }, { "name": "Orange", "price": "2.50", "code": "SGD" } ] }');

    const select = document.createElement("select");
    select.id = 'currency';
    select.onchange = ({target: {value}}) => console.log(value);

    products.forEach(({code, name}) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.label = name;
        option.value = code;
        select.appendChild(option);
    });

    const main = document.getElementById('main');
    main.appendChild(select);
</script>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Add the "value" as a param of the function

```
<select id="currency" onchange="getSelectValue(value)">
    <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="MR">Malaysia Riggit</option>
</select>
```

and the function definition should look like this:

```
const getSelectValue = (selectedValue) => {
    console.log(selectedValue);
    // Your code...
};
```

Comment: sorry i tried but is not what i am looking for

Comment: actually I am trying to create a dropdown list that can change the "code" and "price" when I select other currency in the dropdown list.

Comment: so when I select on USD the "price" and "code" can change to USD (now it is in SGD).

Comment: So you don't want to create a dropdown, you want to trigger an update on the products list when the selected option change, am i right?

Comment: yes yes a drop down I actually know how to create is just i don't know how can i do the price and code update..

Comment: for "code" i tried doing : function getSelectValue() 
{
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("currency").value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
    
    document.getElementById("allcurrency").innerHTML=
        multicurrency.currency.code[multicurrency.currency.code.selectedIndex].text
    
}

Comment: but is not changing....

Comment: Try to add the value in the params of the function:

    <select id="currency" onchange="getSelectValue(value)">

And

function getSelectValue(selectedValue) { 
   console.log(selectedValue);
}

Comment: You don't need to find de param by using "document.getElementById", the value is already in the param of the function that you set "onchange".

Comment: because on json file i have "code" so i have been trying to get that portion update when ever I click a different currency

Answer (score -3):

Here is the code sample.

```
var json=JSON.parse( "Your json which you mentioned above");

var products= json.products;



string selectlist="";

if(products.length>0)
{
    
    selectlist += "<select>";
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {


        var currency = json[i];

            selectlist += "<option value="+currency.code+"> "+currency.code+"  </option>";
    }   
    selectlist += "</select>"
if("body").append(selectlist);
}
```